# integrate react and react-fontawesome

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

The react-fontawesome documentation suggests to create a custom library, to only include the icons one needs.

They say to do as follow:

- Add required packages.
- Create custom library like so:

  ```
  import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
  import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
  import { faStroopwafel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

  library.add(faStroopwafel);
  ```
- Use custom library like so:

  ```
   import React from 'react'
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

       ...
       return(<FontAwesomeIcon icon="stroopwafel" />);
  ```

The question is about the 2nd step: is it possible to create a separate file for the library creation? I don't like the idea of having a long list of icons in my application entry point.

What confuses me is that there isn't anything to export, since is it is only a function call (library.add). Should I export a self calling function that executes the library creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Edit 71yv4pw3nq]

Maybe you can write a file that contains your filled library :

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faStroopwafel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faStroopwafel);
```

And in your main file, only import this library and `FontAwesomeIcon`:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import "./MyLib"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="stroopwafel" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit** : Thanks to @mwilkerson for the improved version

Comment: Yes, and you could make it just a bit more tidy by removing the `export` from `MyLib.js` and do the import as `import "./MyLib"`. The idea is that you are importing "for side effects only", not for binding any exports. The side effect in question is the invocation of `library.add()`. See forked CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qvw0q92nyw

Comment: You're right, thanks for this ! i'll edit the answer .